# Using ansible find module to get hidden folders

Tags: ansible

How to use the ansible find module to get folder that start with dot (eg .git). The following example does not work.

```
 - name: Locating all files in files dir    
   find:
     path: "/tmp/test"
     patterns: ".git"
#     recurse: yes
#     use_regex: true    register: cleanup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for the `find` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html), you'll note that by default it only finds files. Because `.git` is a *directory* it will never match. You can modify this behavior using the `file_type` option.

It also explicitly excludes "hidden" files; you can control this behavior with the `hidden` option.

That gives you:

```
- name: Locating all files in files dir    
  find:
    path: "/tmp/test"
    patterns: ".git"
    hidden: true
    file_type: any
```

This  will find files *or* directories named `.git`. If you're looking
for *anything* that starts with `.`, you would write:

```
- name: Locating all files in files dir    
  find:
    path: "/tmp/test"
    patterns: ".*"
    hidden: true
    file_type: any
```

If I have a file named `/tmp/test/.foo` and a directory named `/tmp/test/.bar`, running this playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Locating all files in files dir
      register: res
      find:
        path: "/tmp/test"
        patterns: ".*"
        hidden: true
        file_type: any

    - debug:
        var: res
```

Results in:

```
TASK [Locating all files in files dir] *****************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "res": {
        "changed": false,
        "examined": 2,
        "failed": false,
        "files": [
            {
                "atime": 1628171545.1114912,
                "ctime": 1628171545.1114912,
                "dev": 44,
                "gid": 1000,
                "gr_name": "lars",
                "inode": 9302,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": false,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": true,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mode": "0664",
                "mtime": 1628171545.1114912,
                "nlink": 1,
                "path": "/tmp/test/.foo",
                "pw_name": "lars",
                "rgrp": true,
                "roth": true,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 0,
                "uid": 1000,
                "wgrp": true,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": false,
                "xoth": false,
                "xusr": false
            },
            {
                "atime": 1628171547.4475772,
                "ctime": 1628171547.4475772,
                "dev": 44,
                "gid": 1000,
                "gr_name": "lars",
                "inode": 9303,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": true,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": false,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mode": "0775",
                "mtime": 1628171547.4475772,
                "nlink": 2,
                "path": "/tmp/test/.git",
                "pw_name": "lars",
                "rgrp": true,
                "roth": true,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 40,
                "uid": 1000,
                "wgrp": true,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": true,
                "xoth": true,
                "xusr": true
            }
        ],
        "matched": 2,
        "msg": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set parameter [*hidden*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#parameter-hidden) (*default=no*). For example, given one hidden directory `.git`, two other directories, and two files in `/tmp/test`

```
shell> ls -1a /tmp/test/
.
..
dir1
dir2
file1
file2
.git
```

the task below finds all items in the directory except the hidden one

```yaml
    - find:
        path: /tmp/test
        file_type: any
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.files|map(attribute='path')
```

gives

```yaml
  result.files|map(attribute='path'):
  - /tmp/test/file2
  - /tmp/test/file1
  - /tmp/test/dir2
  - /tmp/test/dir1
```

When you set *`hidden=yes`*

```yaml
    - find:
        path: /tmp/test
        file_type: any
        hidden: yes
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.files|map(attribute='path')
```

the hidden items will be included in the list

```yaml
  result.files|map(attribute='path'):
  - /tmp/test/file2
  - /tmp/test/file1
  - /tmp/test/dir2
  - /tmp/test/dir1
  - /tmp/test/.git
```